# syntax for encoding a particular string in Asp .Net framework 4.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Syntax for encoding a particular string in Asp .Net framework 4.0
Please answer this question.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option C is the answer in case of Asp .Net framework 4.0